# Implementing Tinymce in my CodeIgniter app

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, tinymce

So I'm creating a simple CMS for my own use. So obviously i want to use Tinymce for my text editing. Im trying to implement it in a simple view, but it return nothing. No errors in the console, but it doesn't load Tinymce.

I followed this simple CI guide:

https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/TinyMCE

So this is my simple view:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TEST</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src='<?php echo asset_url()."js/jquery.js" ?>'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='<?php echo asset_url()."js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js" ?>'>
    tinyMCE.init({
        theme : "advanced",
        mode : "textareas",
        plugins : "imagemanager,filemanager,insertdatetime,preview,emotions,visualchars,nonbreaking",
        theme_advanced_buttons1_add: 'insertimage,insertfile',
        theme_advanced_buttons2_add: 'separator,forecolor,backcolor',
        theme_advanced_buttons3_add: 'emotions,insertdate,inserttime,preview,visualchars,nonbreaking',
        theme_advanced_disable: "styleselect,formatselect,removeformat",
        plugin_insertdate_dateFormat : "%Y-%m-%d",
        plugin_insertdate_timeFormat : "%H:%M:%S",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_resize_horizontal : false,
        theme_advanced_resizing : true,
        apply_source_formatting : true,
        spellchecker_languages : "+English=en",
        extended_valid_elements :"img[src|border=0|alt|title|width|height|align|name],"
        +"a[href|target|name|title],"
        +"p,"
        invalid_elements: "table,span,tr,td,tbody,font"

    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
<textarea>
    text..
</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Al i see now is the standard textarea, and not the Tinymce editor. Since the console doesn't give me any feedback at all, I'm kinda clueless where to look for the problem.

Anyone has any experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

Use this script to change your textarea for tinymce:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    tinymce.init({
            selector: "textarea",
            plugins: [
                "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
                "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
                "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
            ],
            toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | fontselect fontsizeselect",
            fontsize_formats: "8pt 10pt 12pt 14pt 18pt 24pt 36pt"
        });

    });
```

I hope it helps

Comment: I still got absolutely nothing. No errors either. It just shows the standard textarea

Comment: @SupSonツ can you check with chrome browser and inspect element, click on network tab, and see if the tinymce scripts loaded. i saw you missed the <head> tag and <script> tag there

Comment: tiny_mce.js and jquery.js are getting loaded fine aswell :)

Answer (score 0):

I added the  start tag which was missing. Try now.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TEST</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src='<?php echo asset_url()."js/jquery.js" ?>'>  </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='<?php echo asset_url()."js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js" ?>'>
<script>
    tinyMCE.init({
        theme : "advanced",
        mode : "textareas",
        plugins : "imagemanager,filemanager,insertdatetime,preview,emotions,visualchars,nonbreaking",
        theme_advanced_buttons1_add: 'insertimage,insertfile',
        theme_advanced_buttons2_add: 'separator,forecolor,backcolor',
        theme_advanced_buttons3_add: 'emotions,insertdate,inserttime,preview,visualchars,nonbreaking',
        theme_advanced_disable: "styleselect,formatselect,removeformat",
        plugin_insertdate_dateFormat : "%Y-%m-%d",
        plugin_insertdate_timeFormat : "%H:%M:%S",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_resize_horizontal : false,
        theme_advanced_resizing : true,
        apply_source_formatting : true,
        spellchecker_languages : "+English=en",
        extended_valid_elements :"img[src|border=0|alt|title|width|height|align|name],"
        +"a[href|target|name|title],"
        +"p,"
        invalid_elements: "table,span,tr,td,tbody,font"

    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
<textarea>
    text..
</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey. that didn't solve it either. And it was already within the script tags from the js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js file :)

Comment: Can you upload to some website and give me the url so that I can identify the issue. Because you are loading lot of themes and it is not available with me. I tried doing a fiddle for this at http://jsfiddle.net/zM5Vp/ you can update the same

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this lines to header

```
<!-- WYSIWYG text editor -->
<script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea' });</script>
```